# 2sxc Blog App - Where Are Module Settings Stored?

Tags: module, settings, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

In the Blog App (I am using 3.00.02 I think), I notice the queries for the main article list have filters for In:Settings:Category. This appears to be Module Settings, but I am not sure. Can you tell me how/where to add and store these settings? I am hoping they are module settings of some kind so I can filter for different types of articles (press vs news vs announcements) on different pages across the site.

Is there an example somewhere in the app of how this filter is used?

Comment: Anyone? I still haven't gotten back to this and hoping for an answer before I do. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Anything on the "In" comes from an in-stream on that data-source. So that block must have an inbound stream called "Settings" - look at where that comes from.